# How To Set PATH (Enviornment Variable) using InstallScript InstallShield

Tags: installation, installshield

I am trying to set Path (Envioenment Variable) using InstallScript for InstallShield 8.
The function EzBatchAddPath("PATH", "C:\Windows", "", AFTER);
can only be used when autoexec.bat is set to ReadOnly=false and Hidden=false.

Are there other methods which can perform the same action without these restriction

Thanks in advance

Comment: Should you be modifying the user's path? Or even worse the system path?  PATH is not unlimited.  If you _really_ need path for your executable, point your icon to a script, that sets PATH then invokes your binary.

Answer (score 1):

Why not update the path at runtime with a wrapper script or similar, what if other executables in the users path conflict with names of your executables? It's a really unreliable solution